# Do videos I "like" on YouTube get shared to people in my circles on Google+?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I would like to know because I don't want everyone seeing what I am doing. I can't find anything to help, so I am asking here. I also have a few friends who are having this problem, but they don't want to create another account, so I am asking for them.

Answer (score 1):

No. Till the time you will not share it with Google+, it won't share automatically. For more you can check your privacy settings, you can control what do you want to share on your Google+ profile.